# Detect a string if it is trimmed or not

Tags: javascript, string, trim

```js
`......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#.........o.o....#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#++++++++++++#..
......##############..
......................`.trim()
```

When I trim the above, it gives me this:

```js
"......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#.........o.o....#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#++++++++++++#..
......##############..
......................"
```

From my understanding, trim removes the whitespace from the beginning and end of the string like in `"  helloworld  "`, the trim will be `"helloworld"`. Now I want to know about the first example that I've defined up above.

First of all, is it even a string because I see backticks there. And if I try to give it quotes the trim won't work. I can't understand or see how it is trimmed. The example is from the [platform game](https://eloquentjavascript.net/16_game.html) in Eloquent JavaScript.

Comment: Backticks are nothing but [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), your string is trimmed

Comment: @KunalMukherjee how come single quotes or double quotes doesn't work? Also, can you tell me how it is trimmed, I mean the whitespace that is removed.

Comment: @htheory226, Because quotes can only go to the next line break - while template literals go to the next `

Comment: @EliasSchablowski I don't follow, sorry :(

Comment: With Single and double quotes you need to [`escape them`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings) for line breaks, with template literals (backticks) it supports line breaks out of the box

Comment: @htheory226 while back ticks and quotes both result in strings, back ticks support multiple lines in the strings.

Comment: Your example string is in fact trimmed, as it doesn't have white spaces at the beginning or the end

Comment: @alotropico sorry for the dumb question but i can't see where the white is removed.

Comment: I wrote an answer trying to pick up on all your doubts. if you have a string and you do .trim() to it the white spaces at the beginning and end get removed, if you mean to say you want to remove double spaces within the string or all new lines please clarify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid in js:

```
"......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#.........o.o....#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#++++++++++++#..
......##############..
......................"
```

This is (as Kunal Mukherjee pointed out in the comments you have to use template literals, which support multiple lines):

```
`......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#.........o.o....#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#++++++++++++#..
......##############..
......................`
```

To answer the question in your title, to check if a string is trimmed you can do this:

```js
function isTrimmed(str) {
  return str == str.trim();
}

const foo = `......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#.........o.o....#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#++++++++++++#..
......##############..
......................`;

console.log(isTrimmed(foo));

console.log(isTrimmed(" Text with space "));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firs of all, is it even a string because I see backticks there. And if I try to give it quotes the trim won't work.

The backticks allow you to define the string over multiple lines. For example a string like this:

```js
let str = `Hello
World`;
```

is actually a string of value `"Hello\nWorld"` (a line feed between the two words). If you replace the backticks with quotes and try to define a string like so:

```js
let str = "Hello
World";
```

then this is not a valid statement. This is the reason why it failed for you. It has nothing to do with trim function.